# r2dbc - This is likely a bug leading to unpredictable outcome

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql

We use `spring-data-r2dbc:1.3.2` and `dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql:0.8.2.RELEASE` and experience a strange issue in production.

We don't understand what is the root cause and whether it is a recoverable or can really create unpredictable outcome (as the log suggests).

Periodically, we see error log as following:

- logger: dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient
- level: ERROR
- message: Exchange cancelled while exchange is active. This is likely
  a bug leading to unpredictable outcome.

We see it a few times a day and it makes us nervous since it explicitly states: **This is likely a bug leading to unpredictable outcome**

We do not get any additional info in the log.

A few questions:

1. Is it really dangerous or can we consider it as a warning?
2. How do we debug it in order to understand its cause?
3. From the source code we could see that it assumes that exchange request cannot be cancelled if it was not completed and consider this situation as a BUG. Does it make sense? What if reactive stream was cancelled due to 'connection drop' or any other reason?

Comment: If you have a semi-reproducible example, you should report it as a bug on the project.

Comment: I'm also using Spring WebFlux 2.7.0 with Java 17. I had mssql-jdbc dependency without mentioning its version, and it automatically picked up 10.*.jre8 I forcefully mentioned the mssql-jdbc version to 10.2.1.jre17 and now started seeing the same message "ReactorNettyClient               : Exchange cancelled while exchange is active. This is likely a bug leading to unpredictable outcome." My reactive driver dependency is "io.r2dbc:r2dbc-mssql:0.9.0.RELEASE"Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I tried deploying my changes to Tanzu Test server with my above changes, and I'm not seeing such error. But, error is still there, when I try to run from my local environment. I'm not sure what is wrong with my local. Old version works well, bumping to new version of mssql-jdbc gives this error in local enviroment.

Comment: I recently migrated to reactive and seeing this error in local.  Were you able to find out what causes it ? .  Have you had any issues in production ?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql/issues/73?